# What is the dart equivalent of RandomAccessFile readLong, readInt in Java

Tags: dart

What would be the equivalent of Java RandomAccessFile **readLong**

in Dart RandomAccessFile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer:

```
var b = await  file.read(8); 
var longVal = b.buffer.asByteData().getUint64(0);
```

or

```
var b = await  file.read(4); 
var longVal = b.buffer.asByteData().getUint32(0);
```

**readLong**  reads a signed 64-bit integer from this file. 
This method reads eight bytes from the file, starting at the current file pointer. 
If the bytes read, in order, are:

b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, and b8, where:

0 <= b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8 <=255,

then the result is equal to:

```
var b = await  file.read(8); //Uint8List
var longVal =   (b[0] << 56) + (b[1] << 48)  + (b[2] << 40) + (b[3] << 32) + (b[4] << 24) + (b[5] << 16) + (b[6] << 8) + b[7];
```

Comment: Wouldn't you use: `b.buffer.asByteData().getUint64(0)`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much.